# How I can make paypal payment in Windows Phone App?

Tags: windows-phone-7, paypal

I want make paypal payments in windows phone app, api does not exist yet, How I can do this using WebBrowser Control?

Comment: PayPal does have a SOAP API - https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference

Comment: Are there any examples of this?

Comment: You mean like if they had a link on the left that said Sample Code? https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code